# "Grouped" ng-repeat with flat JSON in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

In the past, I have done a "grouped" ng-repeat with nested JSON data.  This time, I am stuck with a feed, such as:

```
...{
"name": "Film",
"id": "film",
"unicode": "f008",
"created": 1,
"categories": [
  "Web Application Icons"
]
}, {
"name": "th-large",
"id": "th-large",
"unicode": "f009",
"created": 1,
"categories": [
  "Text Editor Icons"
]
}, {
"name": "th",
"id": "th",
"unicode": "f00a",
"created": 1,
"categories": [
  "Text Editor Icons", "Medical Icons"
]
},...
```

I am trying to create a page with the icons grouped by category, such as

```
Web Application Icons
    -- ng-repeat of matching icons
Text Editor Icons
    -- ng-repeat of matching icons
Medical Icons
    -- ng-repeat of matching icons
```

I tried this to start, which worked once before with data at more than one level:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="i in icons">
<h3 class="sh">{{i.categories[0]}}</h3>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="j in i.children | filter:faIconSearch">
        <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-{{j.id}}"></i> fa-{{j.id}}</p>
   </div>
```

But this does not work here. What did I miss?  (again, I need to work with the data *as is*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to get all the categories:

```
$scope.getCategories = function() {
    var categories = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.icons, function(item) {
      angular.forEach(item.categories, function(category) {
        if (categories.indexOf(category) == -1) {
          categories.push(category);
        }
      })
    });
    return categories;
  }
```

Now you can loop over the categories, and inside that loop over all the icons, filtering only the ones with a matching category.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="cat in getCategories()">
  <h3>{{cat}}</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="icon in icons | filter:{categories: cat}">
    <span style="margin-left: 20px">{{icon.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bpDZkucSP7HXyHe2dmBS?p=preview)

Comment: I posted the question as I am new to Angular. I tried several methods of doing it on my own and Googling. As it turns out, even a more experienced colleague of mine did not know this method. so I am in debt to Jerrad for his/her help on this.  Now I have learned something that I can adapt further, and I can pay it forward by helping others.  This is how I learned everything on the computer for the past 20 years; people who are helpful and share what they know.  It's not a video game where I want coy "hints".

Comment: @Steve So basically, you already know `ngRepeat`, you already know `filter`, you already know how to bind `{{someData}}` to HTML, since you're using them in your question. What have you learned from this answer?

Comment: My colleague was pointing me to an elaborate underscore.js method of doing this, which would've killed hours of time, providing it actually worked.  It was already twice the code here. I did not know this structure in Angular; in fact, my more experienced colleague didn't think of doing it this way. So I learned a pure angular approach to this problem instead of falling back on my better-known jquery and underscore. I consider this progress.

Comment: @Steve Exactly: "structure", "approach". So basically, an answer with the keywords for each step would have been enough for you, and you'll have progressed by writing the code yourself. Oh! It reminds me of something… Not you?